# Email Campaign manager: $name$ is not replaced on the online version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.1, sitecore-ecm

I am using Sitecore 7.1 MVC and added the aspx version of `ProcessPersonilizationToken` sublayout on my view.

I can see the personalization token replaced by the recipient name but it does not work on the online version it displays `$name`.

Where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you found the solution for this? I have the same issue.